# Map object support in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Does Google Apps Script supports the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object?

When I try to use it I get:

```
ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined. (line 21, file "Code")
```

Comment: As of February 5th 2020 they added support for es6 and now can run scripts on v8. Just enable it in the menu Run.

Answer (score 10):

No. Map was introduced in ES6. Google Apps Script roughly corresponds to ES 5.1. It runs on [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino#Rhino_documentation), which is not so actively developed, and it's not clear if Google will ever want to pull in newer Rhino releases anyway.

Comment: Is there an alternative to "Map" in Rhino?

Answer (score 3):

Now is possible by changing your script to use the new runtime that runs on V8.
Enable it in the menu "Run/Enable new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8"

```
function testMap(){
  var m = new Map();
  m.set("a", "value")
  Logger.log(m.get("a"));
}
```

Output:

```
[20-02-16 12:25:42:404 CST] value
```