# Compare two arrays and obtain only one with data matching colum 1 in javascript/ google-apps-script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm not very experienced in javascript, but I've been trying to find a solution to my problem without success.
I have 3 arrays with 15000 rows and 39 columns and I need to compare them to extract only values ​​that match the conditions I need in a single array.

So far I've got this code and it works but only can compare about 1000 lines at a time. There is some quicker solution that I am not finding? 
Already tried to look for several solutions and adpatar but I could not find a similar problem.

Any help is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
// ...definition of variables...
var newData = data3;
var novo =[]
var novo2 =[]
for(var i in data){
    var duplicate = false;
    for(var j in newData){
        //compare only if >0 to dont spend time in script
       if(data[i][33] > 0 || data[i][30] > 0 || newData[j][33] > 0 || newData[j][30] > 0) {
           //compare first column
           if(data[i].slice(0,1).toString() == newData[j].slice(0,1).toString()) {
               duplicate = true;
               var nd = newData[j].slice(30,34)
           }
       }
    }
    if(duplicate){
        novo.push(data[i].slice(0,4))
        novo2.push(nd)
    }
 }
 //set the values
```

Edited:
Each row is with this type of data:

[3976.0, Talonete c/rebordo maf sindolor .med., 20.8, 14.61, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Sun Sep 18 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2011, Wed Aug 20 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014, 0.0, ORTOMEDIFAR-IMPORTAÇAO E DISTRIBUIÇAO DE ARTIGOS MEDICA, Laboratórios Iberpos, S.A, GH0000, 0.0]

[4286.0, PULSO ELASTICO TAM 1 BEIJE, 5.15, 3.2, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Thu Oct 12 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2017, Thu Oct 12 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2017, 2.0, N/D, N/D, GH0000, 0.0]

[80105.0, LIMA LASER COM PEGA, 6.35, 3.65, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Wed Jun 24 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2015, Tue Jul 09 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013, 0.0, N/D, N/D, GH0000, 0.0]

Comment: Can you explicitly mention the conditions in the question?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @void I think with the code sniped you can understand, but 
briefly, I intend to compare column 1 of each array and add in the same row data from the arrays that are present if the values ​​are greater than 0

Comment: @SérgioSá we can improve your code, but please share some of the data in order that we can make the code run. Just some 5-10 records is enough

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Thank You, I Edited My Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save time by first creating a "hash" for your data, keyed by `item.slice(0,1).toString()`, and then you can find matches without having to iterate your data -- instead the hash will give you the match in constant time if there is one. With ES5 you can use a plain object to implement such a hash:

```
// Create the hash:
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    map[item.slice(0,1).toString()] = item;
}

// Iterate the newData array and match with the hash: 
for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    var item = newData[i];
    var match = map[item.slice(0,1).toString()];
    if (match) {
        novo.push(match.slice(0,4))
        novo2.push(item.slice(30,34))
    }
}
```

NB:  I did not include the `> 0` tests to keep the solution to the essence, but you can of course still do that.

Comment: @tricot thank's. you probably going to kill me, but I did not say it was in google appscript and it gives me an error: syntax error. (line 81, file "Code") which is: ` var map = new Map(data, item => [item.slice(0,1).toString(), item]);`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990547/map-object-support-in-google-apps-script) ES6 is not suportaded :(

Comment: Amazing, very fast, but how can I compare with a 3th array? and get something like 'novo3.push(match2.slice(35,36)'?

Comment: That really is a new question. What would you want to compare the third array with? With `data`, with `newData` or with both? You can create a second hash, or combine two arrays in one hash, but it all depends on what exactly want to compare with. Maybe you should try it yourself first, and then if you still bump into a problem, ask a specific (new) question about that.

Comment: You are right, is an other question. 
I intend to compare with the result of your code, but I solved this by setting the values ​​in the Spreadsheet and returning to use the same code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tested only with the data you sent. But I think like this should be much faster. Please test with the full data. Ask you you didn't understand some of the code. I used only ES5 as you said you're using ES5 in Google appscript

```js
var data1 = [
[3976.0, 'Talonete c/rebordo maf sindolor .med.', 20.8, 14.61, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 777.0, 0.0, 'Sun Sep 18 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2011', 'Wed Aug 20 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014', 0.0, 'ORTOMEDIFAR-IMPORTAÇAO E DISTRIBUIÇAO DE ARTIGOS MEDICA, Laboratórios Iberpos, S.A', 'GH0000', 0.0],
[4286.0, 'PULSO ELASTICO TAM 1 BEIJE', 5.15, 3.2, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 'Thu Oct 12 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2017', 'Thu Oct 12 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2017', 2.0, 'N/D', 'N/D', 'GH0000', 0.0],
[80105.0, 'LIMA LASER COM PEGA', 6.35, 3.65, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 555.0, 1.0, 'Wed Jun 24 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2015', 'Tue Jul 09 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013', 0.0, 'N/D', 'N/D', 'GH0000', 0.0] ];
var data2 = [
[3976.0, 'Talonete c/rebordo maf sindolor .med.', 20.8, 14.61, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 333.0, 0.0, 'Sun Sep 18 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2011', 'Wed Aug 20 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014', 0.0, 'ORTOMEDIFAR-IMPORTAÇAO E DISTRIBUIÇAO DE ARTIGOS MEDICA, Laboratórios Iberpos, S.A', 'GH0000', 0.0],
[4286.0, 'PULSO ELASTICO TAM 1 BEIJE', 5.15, 3.2, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 'Thu Oct 12 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2017', 'Thu Oct 12 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2017', 2.0, 'N/D', 'N/D', 'GH0000', 0.0],
[80105.0, 'LIMA LASER COM PEGA', 6.35, 3.65, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 'Wed Jun 24 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2015', 'Tue Jul 09 23:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013', 0.0, 'N/D', 'N/D', 'GH0000', 0.0] ];

var novo =[], novo2 =[];

filter = function(e){ return ((e[30] > 0) || (e[33] > 0)); };
data1 = data1.filter(filter);
data2 = data2.filter(filter);
data1.map(function(row1) {
    var slice = row1.slice(0,1).toString();
    var nd = data2
        .filter(function(row2) { return slice == row2.slice(0,1).toString();})
        .map(function(row2) { return row2.slice(30,34); });
    if (nd) nd.map(function(rowNd) {
        novo.push(rowNd.slice(0,4));
        novo2.push(rowNd);} );
})

console.log(novo, novo2)
```

Also my experience with Google Appscript showed that the slowest thing is getting the values from and updating the spreadsheet. So try to use sheet.getRange().setValues() and .getValues() so you can get/set many values at a time instead of reading and writing cell by cell.

Comment: I c'ant understand how to use filter,(giv-me an error) but any way, without that, the resulte is 2 times item 30-34. thanks any way

Comment: Filter is really simple to use. Read this and if you have any doubt just ask: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Comment: se vc precisar de algum auxílio em português é só abrir um chat :)